# How to keep track of current and previous iterator on a c++ vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have one vector container and I would like to make a subtraction operation on the values of its content using the current iterator against the previous iterator, any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Just curious, why not just use `[]` operator and do operations based on the index ?

Comment: @Mahesh, pretend it's a map or set instead of a vector. The question is a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector`'s iterator is a [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), so you can perform integer arithmetic on it. Thus, you don't need a separate "current" and "previous" pointer, as long as you start your iteration from `begin() + 1`:

```
vector<Foo> myVec = ...;
if(myVec.size() > 1) { 
    for(vector<Foo>::iterator iter = myVec.begin()+1; iter != myVec.end(); iter++) {
        Foo current = *iter;
        Foo previous = *(iter - 1);
        Foo subtraction = current - previous;
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, you can't subtract the current and previous element if there are fewer than two elements in your vector. The size check might be redundant if you know your input vector will always have at least two elements, but I included it just to be safe.

Comment: If myVec.begin() == myVec.end() you have undefined behaviour

Comment: Good point. I guess I assumed the OP's vector would always be non-empty because he wanted to subtract the current item from the previous item, but I can fix it to make sure it doesn't break on empty vectors.

Answer (score 6):

```
vector<MyClass>::iterator itPrevious = my_vec.begin();
vector<MyClass>::iterator itCurrent = itPrevious;
if (itCurrent != my_vec.end())
{
    for (++itCurrent;  itCurrent != my_vec.end();  ++itCurrent)
    {
        // do something with itPrevious and itCurrent
        itPrevious = itCurrent;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean `itCurrent` in `for (itCurrent;`?

Comment: @TooTone, I was unsure what to put in the first part of the `for` loop since it doesn't really require anything in this case. I thought it would look too odd leaving it blank so I just threw in a do-nothing clause.

Comment: I thought you could put the `++itCurrent` in there and then have the `for` as the `if` body?

Comment: @TooTone, now I understand. That's a good suggestion, I'll make that change.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to keep separate "current" and "previous" iterators when iterator arithmetic can get a pointer to the previous value on the spot?

Comment: @Edward having two iterators is more flexible if you don't know the exact operations that will be performed in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(v.size() < 2)
   return;
auto curr = v.begin();
auto next = curr;
++next;
do
{
  whatever(*next - *curr );
  curr = next++;
} while( next != v.end() )
```

Answer (score 2):

Given you asked for a vector, you can use iterator arithmetic:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    for ( auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i ) {
        if ( i != v.begin() )
            *i = *i - *(i-1);
    }
    for ( auto i : v )
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
for (auto previous = v.begin(), current = previous + 1, end = v.end();
    previous != end && current != end;
    ++previous, ++current)
{
    std::cout << *current << " - " << *previous << " = " << *current - *previous << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are namely three more-or-less elegant ways to solve your problem.

### Define a new functor

And use it in a `for_each` iteration

```
template<class T>
struct substractor {
    substractor() : last(nullptr) {}
    void operator()(T& item) const
    {
        if(last != nullptr)
            *last -= item;
        last = &item;
    }
    mutable T* last;
};
...
vector<int> v = {3, 2, 1};
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), substractor<int>());
```

### Define a new algorithm

Some kind of pair in-place transform here

```
template<typename It, typename Op>
void pair_transform(It begin, It end, Op op){
    while(begin != end)
    {
        It next = std::next(begin);
        if(next == end) break;
        *begin = op(*begin, *next);
        ++begin;
    }
}
...
vector<int> w = {3, 2, 1};
pair_transform(w.begin(), w.end(), std::minus<int>());
```

### Keep it standard, use transform

IMHO the best one :) Concise, standard, nowhere else to look in order to understand this code.

```
vector<int> z = {3, 2, 1};
std::transform(z.begin(), z.end() - 1, z.begin() + 1, z.begin(), 
    std::minus<int>());
```